# How to build x[0] + x[1] > 0 constraint in scipy.optimize.minimize?

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, minimize

I am trying to build the right constraint to minimize the objetive function:

```
fun_SV = lambda x : objective(value_date_2, datos_2,curve,'Svensson',curve_rates,fechas_tenors,x)
```

I have a list of parameters `x` and I just want a constraint in which the sum of the first and second parameter was greater to 0 I am trying this:

```
cons = {'type':ineq, 'fun': lambda x: x[0] + x [1]}
```

Then, I minimize:

```
bounds_sv = ((0,15),(-15,30),(-30,30),(-30,30),(0.000000001,30)(0.000000001,30))

res_SV = minimize(fun_SV, x0,method="SLSQP", bounds= bounds_sv, constraints = my_constraints, tol=0.000001,options={'maxiter':50000})
```

what i get is both that the sum of both are 0 and I just want `x[0] + x[1] > 1`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you pls share with us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Answer (score 0):

SLSQP has inequalities of the form `f(x)>=0`. So if you want `g(x)>1` you must use: `f(x)-1.0001>=0`. In your case:

```
 cons = {'type':ineq, 'fun': lambda x: x[0] + x [1] - 1.0001 }
```